# Can't get Google cloud storage working on CKAN 2.1a

Tags: google-cloud-storage, ckan

I installed the CKAN from source and trying to activate the Cloud Filestore option without success.

I double-checked my Google API console and activated interoperable access keys (GOOG...) to no avail. I keep getting "Unable to Upload File" when I try to upload.

Comment: Can i suggest opening an issue and posting details for this item at https://github.com/okfn/ckan/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get it to work so just switched to S3 which was more straightforward.  The recent S3 price drops helped too :)

Comment: Oopps... sorry. On a sidenote, if there is any flexibility in choosing cloud storage systems for CKAN, the underlying python boto project (https://github.com/boto/boto) has far more robust support for AWS, so that should factor in to your choice of CKAN cloud storage.